# Search Algo Complexity: Number of times you can take 3/4th of a number until it is less than or equal to 1

Tags: algorithm, search, complexity-theory

I'm working on a variant of binary search that narrows the search space down to 3/4th its original size every iteration and am wondering how you'd go about figuring out its runtime.

My intuition says it's log base (4/3) of N (where N = the size of the array you're searching) but I'm struggling to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Here is a proof:

Let's take it from the reversed direction. We arrived at a value 0 < *n* ≤ 1. Before the last iteration, *n* must have been such that:

1 < *n* ≤ 4/3,

Before the one-but-last iteration:

4/3 < *n* ≤ (4/3)²

and so on... So backtracking *k* iterations we get:

(4/3)<sup>*k*−1</sup> < *n* ≤ (4/3)<sup>*k*</sup>

If we take the (4/3)-base logarithm of all parts in this inequality:

*k* − 1 < log<sub>4/3</sub>*n* ≤ *k*

So if you round that logarithm *up*, you get *k*, which represented the number of iterations.